# django.utils.encoding.DjangoUnicodeDecodeError : utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 15: invalid start byte. You passed in 'Une tentative

Tags: python, django

probleme avec python manage.py runserver 
django.utils.encoding.DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 15: invalid start byte. You passed in 'Une tentative d\x92acc\xe8s \xe0 un socket de mani\xe8re interdite par ses autorisations d\x92acc\xe8s a \xe9t\xe9 tent\xe9e' ()

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767848/django-utils-encoding-djangounicodedecodeerror

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django.utils.encoding.DjangoUnicodeDecodeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767848/django-utils-encoding-djangounicodedecodeerror)